# Raspberry Pi can ping others but can not be pinged

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, ping

I am new to Raspberry Pi.

I have two Raspberry Pi. One of them is connected internet via Wifi dongle. I can ping others in the network and can be pinged from others. But the second one has connected the internet via an ethernet cable. I can ping others in the network (included the other raspberry pi) but can not be pinged from others.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the AP isolation in the access point is disabled?

Comment: @M.Rostami Yes, I am sure because all of them in the network can ping each other but except this raspberry pi.

Comment: Do you mean that another raspberry pi has the same situation that works well?

Comment: @M. Rostami , Yes, only difference between them is connection type. One is wireless the other one is ethernet. Sorry for the late answers. It is because of time zone.

Comment: Try another network manager. `sudo apt-get install wicd`. I think it's gonna solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the two Raspberries around: I would expect that the one you connect via the Ethernet will still be the one that cannot be pinged.

The problem then lies in the router (or whatever device you have which provides the Internet access to the rest of your network). `ping` sends data via Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP), so that's what you should look for in the settings.

Comment: @NetworkDan Nice catch, thanks.